# Select using recursivity to iterate node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback

i'm iterating trought a mysql database with 20000 rows , the problem is that in each roww i need to call a url and get its content and update the database, the problem is... how do i wait the whole process to continue the iteration?, and how can i make it faster like , do two at time , do tree at time?. thanks

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT * from product where product.product_description = "0" ', function(err, rows, fields) {
        kontador =1;
        if (!err)
        {
            var url = rows[0].url;
            url = url.replace('../..','');
            //console.log(url);
            id = rows[0].id;
            url = 'http://example.com'+url;


            doCall(url,id,kontador,function(response){
                console.log(response,kontador);

                if(response && kontador <= rows.length){

                    var url = rows[kontador].url;
                    url = url.replace('../..','');
                    id = rows[kontador].id;

                    url = 'http://www.example2.com'+url;
                    //console.log(id);

                    doCall(url,id, kontador, doCall);
                    kontador +=1;

                }

            });


        }
        else
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    });

function doCall(urlToCall,id,kontador, callback) 
{
    request({'url':urlToCall}, function(error, response, html){
            //console.log('inside');
            //console.log(error);
            if(!error){

                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                $('#content').filter(function(){
                     var data = $(this);
                     data = data.find('p');
                     // console.log('-');
                     // console.log(data.html());

                     var queryy = connection.query(' UPDATE product SET  product_description = "'+data.html()+'"  WHERE id = '+id, function(err, rows, fields) {
                        if (!err)
                        {
                            console.log('updated! ');
                             return callback(true);
                        }else{
                            console.log('error sql!');
                        }
                    });


                    //process.exit();
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to orchestrate the async behavior of your application (what can be done in parallel, should there be throttling, ..) you should use an existing library like :

- async - https://www.npmjs.com/package/async - if you prefer node.js callback style
- bluebird - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html - if you prefer promises
- highland - https://www.npmjs.com/package/highland - somewhat hybrid + stream like

There are many other libraries that can help you build complex async call graphs.